# What is The difference between creating constructor in heap or in stack?

Tags: c++

Here is a basic example

```
myclass * abc = new myclass()
```

and

```
myclass abc
```

What is the difference? In both situations, is the object `abc` created in stack? If the object is created in heap, what does differ?

From the answers, I take that (please edit if incorrect):

1. Constructor initializes class (members)
2. If we want the variables of class not deleted when it is out of scope, we should take object creation to heap.

Comment: You mean besides the objects are stored in different places? And that you need a pointer for the heap-allocated object? Perhaps you can elaborate a little on what's bothering you or what you're wondering about?

Comment: And that you need to (manually) manage the destruction for the object allocated using `new` (while the other one will be automatically destroyed when its lifetime ends)

Comment: I mean in both codes the object abc created in stack right ? how creating constructor in heap can effect the code ?

Comment: Terminology, please. You are not 'creating [a] constructor` here at all. You are creating an *object*, either on the heap or on the stack, *and* a *variable*, always on the stack, assuming this code is in a method, which isn't stated. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although in both cases `abc` is in the automatic memory (commonly called "stack") it is not the same kind of object:

- In the first example `abc` is a pointer, which is stored on the stack. However, there is a second object of type `myclass` which is stored in dynamic memory (commonly called "heap"). Object pointer `abc` points to the object in the heap.
- In the second example `abc` is of type `myclass`. This is the only object being created.

Main difference between the two approaches is that an object created in dynamic memory can "outlive" the function inside of which it is created. When the pointer `abc` goes out of scope, its heap object remains active. For example, you can return it from a function without making a copy.

Comment: @StelTeam You will be accessing your object through a pointer, which is different syntax. You will need to delete the object manually by calling `delete`.

Comment: and 1 more thing if pointer goes out scope then how can I access the object ?

Comment: @StelTeam You can keep the object accessible by storing a pointer to it in another pointer with a different scope, or by returning it to the caller from the function.

Answer (score 1):

In `myclass * abc = new myclass();` you create a pointer to myclass on the stack and an instance of myclass on the heap. While in `myclass abc;` you create the instance of myclass on the stack.

There are many differences, but the most straight forward one is that the stack is freed when you leaving the current context (for example return from a function) while the heap remain. So in the first example the instance of myclass will remain in the memory until you free it manually while in the second option it will be cleared automatically when you exit from the function or code block it is written in.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of constructor invocation, there is basically no difference between the two. In both cases, the default constructor of class is invoked to build an object. It is just that in case of `myclass * abc = new myclass()`, the new operator returns a pointer to the newly created object.

However, the main difference lies in the concept of stack memory and heap (dynamic) memory. The expression `myclass * abc = new myclass()` allocates the memory for the newly created object from heap while `myclass abc` allocates it from stack. One implication of this difference is that you are responsible for the memory that you have requested from heap and you have to deallocate it yourself while for variables that are allocated on the stack, the compiler does the job of memory deletion for you. Consider the following simple function:

```
void fo()
{
    myclass * abc1 = new myclass();
    myclass abc2; 

    // Use the declared variables.

    // At the end, is everything OK?
}
```

In case of this function, when the function returns, the memory of the `abc2`is automatically freed by compiler. Compiler also deletes the `abc1` pointer but does not do anything about the memory that this pointer points to. This subtle feature leads to the [notorious memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) leak in this function. The following modified version of `fo` addresses this mistake:

```
void fo()
{
    myclass * abc1 = new myclass();
    myclass abc2; 

    // At the end, manually free the memory that abc1 points to if it is not needed anymore
    delete abc1
}
```

Wikipedia has a [very nice article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) about the concept of heap and stack memory that gives more information about them and provides more details.